# Why is this password not good enough?

Tags: password

I was changing my password on Ubuntu 14.04 and wondering why is this password not good enough:

`pr#cur@rempr_3go!`

[image]

My current password is `procurar@empr3go!`

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes! It would let me change my password if I try this way: pr#cur@rempr_3!go

Comment: are you using utf-8 or another encoding? Possible: the ! at then end? Can you confirm that is the problem? when I change my pwd I get "strong" :D weirrrd

Comment: utf-8. this is an english (US) version of Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AhtKZ.png - it works for me... Very odd!

Comment: I can't duplicate this. When I typed the exact password it says strong

Comment: Could it be you are inserting the SAME password as you currently have?

Comment: Nah, but close. I think this happens because my current password has "go!" at the end.

Comment: Maybe you just found a bug. @Tim: your pic and his pic look different, he's changing the password typing the old one first. It shouldn't make any difference, but reproducing bugs should be as accurate as possible. Anyway that is useful too because we know a way it works. Thanks for sharing :) vrcca: can you do it that way?

Comment: Yes, adding a new user works. But here is what i figured out: my current password is: procurar@empr3go! and when I try to change to: pr#cur@rempr_3go! it fails. But if I try: pr#cur@rempr_3!go, it works. I think that the software is checking my current password for repetition.

Comment: @vrcca: Just for the sake of security, you should never ever post your passwords anywhere.

Comment: In addition to what @CijcoSistems said, change your password again and DON'T POST IT. It doesn't matter how secure it is if you tell everyone...

Comment: Thank you, but i don't use that password anywhere. That was just a test! :) Btw, I just changed it hehe

Comment: It's not good enough because it's now on the Internet ;)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think this answers my question: [A strong password is significantly different from your previous password.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StrongPasswords#line-19):

> Strong Passwords
>
> Applications, and libraries exist for your Ubuntu system to assist in
>   generating, or enforcing strong passwords. A strong password is
>   defined as any password which meets the following criteria:
>
> 1. At least fifteen (15) characters in length.
> 2. Does not contain your user name, real name, organization name, family member's names or names of your pets.
> 3. Does not contain your birth date.
> 4. Does not contain a complete dictionary word.
> 5. **Is significantly different from your previous password.**
> 6. Should contain three (3) of the following character types.
>          Lowercase Alphabetical (a, b, c, etc.)
>          Uppercase Alphabetical (A, B, C, etc.)
>          Numerics (0, 1, 2, etc.)
>          Special Characters (@, %, !, etc.)

Since my current password and the new password ends with `3go!`, Ubuntu won't let me reuse it.

Thank you all!

Comment: excellent! upvote and accept as soon as you can. On AU it is custom to add important parts to the answer (as links tend to disappear). so I added a little bit from the wiki ;)

Comment: If passwords are hashed/salted, how could this be compared?

Comment: @Wchargin Did you notice the place in that dialog where it says `"current password: ***********"` ?

Comment: I don't think the problem is merely that both passwords ends with "3go!".  Ubuntu would probably accept "Correct Horse Battery Staple 3go!" with no warning.  The problem is that one can optain the new password from the old by making few changes.  Your new password only needs 4 changes; o to #, remove @, a to @, remove _.

Comment: @Shadur Ah—so it compares the new password to the password you entered as current, and verifies that the current password is correct (`a = b; b = c` → `a = c`). That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

The reason it is not allowed is because you have enabled (somewhere - during installation?) to make you change every 72 days. This also disallows you from using the last password (and maybe ones before it, but it may only be the previous ones (See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492082/why-is-this-password-not-good-enough#comment658314_492090) comment).

Workaround:

This is clearly a strong password (or it was before you posted it), unless it had been used for another user or before for that user. I would suggest you add the user via terminal, as that doesn't have secure password requirements (but use one that isn't out there for the world to see, and please change your password soon, everyone knows it now). We can guess what your username is on your pc, probably the same as all your social networking accounts, and then your IP address can theoretically be traced through twitter of Facebook etc. NB: I'm not a hacker and I might be able to break in (I won't try), so a hacker would find it easily.

To change with terminal.

```
sudo adduser <username>
passwd <username>
```

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: I haven't enabled password expiration, but thanks!

Comment: *'This is clearly a strong password'* - not if you write it down and post it online...

Comment: ...so you *did* just post your live password you use everywhere, just with like one character changed or something. An attacker could have instantly recognized why your password was rejected while you were still hoping someone would figure it out and generously post it.

Comment: Does this also mean that my past passwords are stored in plaintext somewhere?

Comment: Not unless you use a 3rd party app that does.

Comment: @djechlin It doesn't matter because it wouldn't be worth hacking. It was a clean installation. Anyway, thanks for the explanation! :)